# how to run .dump command in linux?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, java, sqlite

I want to create dump file of sqlite database from java but I can't run the below command from linux. I got the help of windows and I tried with linux but it appears one terminal nothing more than that. So can anyone help me how to write this command in linux?

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /b sqlite3 db.sqlite .dump > dump.txt");
```

My implementation in Linux is below:

```
String command= "/usr/bin/xterm"; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{command , "/home/ubuntu/test.sqlite .dump > /home/ubuntu/newsql111.sql"});
```

Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
 Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testingdb.sqlite .dump > /home/ubuntu/success11.sql"});
```

It gives full dump file of sqlite database..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an xterm but you do need a sqlite3. That is you are running

```
/usr/bin/xterm /home/ubuntu/test.sqlite .dump > …
```

when you really need to run

```
/bin/sh -c "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/test.sqlite .dump > …"
```

where I am assuming your database is …/test.sqlite. I'll leave the Java specifics to you.

Comment: when i running this code it gives me error..

    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh -c ": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:483)
 at sqlitedbtest.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)

Comment: @msw.. hey when i run this command it works but when i am trying to dump in the folder where space in between name.. at that time does not work?